# Django forms: integrating a submit button as part of your form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So say I had a django views.py file with the following:

```
def addauthorView(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
     f = ContactForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
        user_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        c = Contact(firstname=first_name, lastname=last_name, email=user_email)
     else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'addauthor.html', {'form': ContactForm})
else:
    return render(request, 'addauthor.html', {'form': ContactForm})
```

A forms.py file like such

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname =forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

and a HTML file like such

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Head</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
    {{form.as_ul}}
    <input type="submit">  
    </ul>
</body>
```

How do I make it the case that when the `<input type="submit">` button is pressed, my `ContactForm`view will execute some code. Is there a specific way to group buttons into a forms.py? Or is there any other way to do this. If someone could help me rework this code, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose `form.as_ul` and `submit` button into the `form` tag:

```
<form action="/your_url_here/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_ul }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Also see [Displaying a form using a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I almost thought it wasn't that easy ;P